# Failed to load chunklist_w1087592622.m3u8 in Video.JS

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

Failed to load chunklist_w1087592622.m3u8?e=1534967576&h=3cd169c3f9cf89c3ce679ecc0a989f29: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com/' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

i am generating Secure .m3u8 stream with validity 90sec (https://example.com/bunny/playlist.m3u8?e=1535202970&h=241c3c4ab12b59ca7ac1302497522187)

After 90Sec it get invalid in cansol shows..

video.js:7187 GET https://example.com/bunny/chunklist_w1087592622.m3u8?e=1534967576&h=3cd169c3f9cf89c3ce679ecc0a989f29 403 (Forbidden)
(index):1 Failed to load https://example.com/bunny/chunklist_w1087592622.m3u8?e=1534967576&h=3cd169c3f9cf89c3ce679ecc0a989f29: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com/' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
video.js:128 VIDEOJS: WARN: Problem encountered with the current HLS playlist. Trying again since it is the final playlist.

how to get stream continuous without refresh..